# How many numbers between $1$ and $999,999$ inclusive have exactly two of the digits $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many numbers between $1$ and $999,999$ inclusive have exactly two of the digits $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ at least once?

I am just not too sure where to start on this one. Does anyone have any hints on how to start using the principle of exclusion and inclusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We first count all strings of length $6$ over the alphabet $A:=\{x,y,5,6,7,8,9,0\}$ that contain at least one $x$ and at least one $y$. There are $8^6$ strings in all (we don't have to bother about strings beginning with $0$), then $7^6$ strings that do not contain an $x$ and $7^6$ strings that do not contain a $y$; finally there are $6^6$ strings that contain neither $x$ nor $y$. Using inclusion/exclusion we can therefore say  that there are
$$8^6-2\cdot 7^6+6^6$$
strings of length $6$ over $A$ containing at least one $x$ and at least one $y$. Now from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ we can select ${4\choose2}=6$ pairs $x<y$, and we then can replace $x$ and $y$ in the constructed strings accordingly. It follows that there are
$$6\cdot(8^6-2\cdot 7^6+6^6)=441\,012$$
strings of the desired kind.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you so much.